# How to evaluate bash function arguments as command with possible environment overrides?

Tags: bash, shell

How to write a function in bash (I can rely on it being v4+), that, given words constituting a command with possible environment overrides, execute this command in the current shell?

For example, given

```
f cd src
f CXX="ccache gcc" make -k XOPTIONS="--test1 --test2"
```

the function `f` would do approximately same thing as simply having these lines in the shell script without the `f` up front?

A few unsuccessful attempts. 
This tries to evaluate environment override `CXX="ccache gcc"` as command.

```
f() { "$@" ; }
```

This loses word-quoting on all arguments, breaking single argument words on spaces:

```
f() { eval "$@" ; }
```

This handles the environment overrides, but runs the command in a subshell, as env(1) is not a bash builtin:

```
f() { env -- "$@" ; }
```

This question came up multiple times on SO and Unix SE, but I have never seen it asked about supporting all three important parts, namely: environment overrides; execution in the current shell; and correct handling of arguments containing spaces (and other characters that are lexically special to bash).

One thing I could potentially use is that environment overrides are rarely used  with builtins (but v. `IFS= read...`), so I can select between the `"@" ;` and `eval -- "@" ;` patterns based on `$1` being syntactically a variable assignment. But that is, again, not as simple as spotting a `=` in it, as the equal sign may be quoted part of a command, albeit that is not likely sane. Still, I usually prefer *correct* code to *mostly correct* code, and this approach has 2 consecutive leaps of faith.

Addressing a possible question why do I need a function replicating the default behavior of the shell *("just drop the* `f`*")*: in reality, `f()` is more complex that just running a command, implementing a pattern repeating in the script in a few dozen locations; this is only the part I cannot get right.

Comment: do you mind to explain why that's necessary? I can think of multiple solutions now but none of them are the most elegant choices you can have.

Comment: however, in any case, bash has its own view of the input, so there will be catchas. for example, if for some screwed up reason, i like to name my command `screwed=up`, this looks like a env var assignment completely but you can execute it like a command by quoting it `'screwed=up'`. so quoting is significant here. moreover, quoting is transparent to you, so you are only going to see `screwed=up` as a literal. so how are you going to distinguish these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make `eval` see your arguments properly quoted, it should work. To this end, you can use the `%q` format specification of `printf`, which works as follows:

```
$ printf '%q ' CXX="ccache gcc" make -k XOPTIONS="--test1 --test2"
CXX=ccache\ gcc make -k XOPTIONS=--test1\ --test2
```

This would result in a function like

```
f () { 
    eval "$(printf '%q ' "$@")"
}
```

Notice that this appends an extra space at the end of the command, but this shouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky. You could do this, but it's going to pollute the environment of the shell:

```
f() {
    # process any leading "var=value" assignments
    while [[ $1 == ?*=* ]]; do
        declare -x "$1"
        shift
    done
    "$@"
}
```

---

Just did a quick test: the env vars declared in the function are still local to the scope of the function and will not actually pollute the script's environment.

```
$ f() {
  declare -x FOO=bar
  sh -c 'echo subshell FOO=$FOO'
  echo function FOO=$FOO
}
$ unset foo
$ f
subshell FOO=bar
function FOO=bar
$ echo main shell FOO=$FOO
main shell FOO=
```

Comment: probably run it in a subshell?

Comment: In the question, the OP indicates that subshells are a problem.

Comment: You could keep track of the new variables and `unset` them at the end of the function? I feel my solution is still vulnerable, and this one wouldn't be.